# Returning data with sqladapter returns Cannot find an overload for "Fill" and the argument count

Tags: powershell

I am trying to all the data in table from sql database using powershell. Using that data I can use for a foreach statement and use each field.

I run into the below error:

> "MethodException: Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "Fill" and
> the argument count: "1"."

I have no clue on how to fix this and help will be appeciated

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $constring
$SqlConnection.AccessToken = $AccessToken
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SQLQuery  = "SELECT DISTINCT servername, DBName FROM DBInfo "
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText =  $SQLQuery 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$ReaderValidate

#SQL Adapter - get the results using the SQL Command
$sqlAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLQuery
$dataSet = new-object System.Data.Dataset
$allResults = $sqlAdapter.Fill($SqlCmd.CommandText) 
 
Write-output = "$allResults"

#Close SQL Connection
$sqlConnection.Close();
```

I am using azure function and managed idenitity to access the database. That is the reason I am using "$SqlConnection.AccessToken"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `$DataSet` as the argument to the `$Adapter.Fill()` method:

```
$allResults = $sqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
```

A good way to think of it, you are filling the data set...

Here is the code I frequently use, though it's adapted using the `::New()` method instead of using `New-Object`, an older version of this was written similar to yours.

```
$ConnStr = "Server=<ServerName>,<Port>; Database=<DBName>; Integrated Security=true"
$Query   = "SELECT * FROM <TableName> WHERE <SomeCondition>"
$Conn    = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]::new( $ConnStr )

$Conn.Open()

$Adapter = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter]::new( $Query, $Conn )
$DataSet = [System.Data.DataSet]::new()

[Void]$Adapter.Fill( $DataSet )

$Conn.Close()
```

These are the adapter overloads:

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter new()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter new(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand selectCommand)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter new(string selectCommandText, string selectConnectionString)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter new(string selectCommandText, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection selectConnection)
```

In my code I'm using the third one.  The command text followed by the already instantiated connection object.